# How do I connect to an OpenVPN server and dump the certificate chain presented when connecting?

Tags: ssl-certificate, openvpn, tls

My first thought was to use something like `openssl s_client` but this only supports TCP not UDP and it seems there requires some special magic to get TLS over UDP working, how do I interface with that and get a dump of the certficate chain presented? (I specifically need the certificates, not information about them)

Comment: \*facepalm*, there is a `-dtls1` flag I failed to notice. Not posting this as an answer since I still haven't figured out the  dump-to-file part.

Answer (score 6):

Building on the [mostly complete solution](https://serverfault.com/a/952387/576029) in this thread by Peter Šurda (see there for some explanation regarding the used `openvpn` options), this should do the work to get the server certificates.

I assume you have a working OVPN configuration file in `config.ovpn` and that you are authenticating the client with a username and a password (this can be omitted, depending on your setup).

Prepare working directory:

```
WD=/tmp/openvpn-cert
mkdir $WD
```

Prepare the script to extract the server certificates and some fake credentials file (we don't need to get past successful authentication):

```
echo -e '#!'"/bin/sh\ncp \$peer_cert $WD/server-cert-\$1.pem" >$WD/extract-cert.sh
chmod +x $WD/extract-cert.sh

echo -e "fakeusername\nfakepassword" >$WD/creds.dat
```

Try to connect with `openvpn`:

```
openvpn --config config.ovpn --auth-user-pass $WD/creds.dat --tls-export-cert $WD \
    --script-security 2 --tls-verify $WD/extract-cert.sh --log /dev/null
```

Now you should have the server certificate available in `$WD/server-cert-0.pem` and can operate on it, e.g. get the *notBefore* and *notAfter* dates:

```
openssl x509 -in $WD/server-cert-0.pem -noout -dates
```

The other certificates in the chain will be available in `$WD/server-cert-1.pem` etc. The number comes from the first argument passed to `extract-cert.sh`, which is the certificate depth. See the `--tls-verify` documentation in the [*Script Hooks* section](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn/blob/master/doc/man-sections/script-options.rst#script-hooks) of the man page.

Comment: For monitoring the OpenVPN server certificate expiration, instead of using `openssl` to get the expiration date you could use the following Nagios plugin https://github.com/matteocorti/check_ssl_cert with a command like `check_ssl_cert -H localhost -f /etc/openvpn/server/server.crt -w 15 -c 7`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the certificate chain isn't actually accepted by OpenVPN (for example if you don't have the right CA cert for a server and you aren't sure which CA you actually need), because the script doesn't get run if the certificate fails other checks.

Answer (score 4):

I happen to be running an OpenVPN server in TCP mode, and I can confirm that you **cannot** use `openssl s_client` to get the certificate:

```
[me@risby 17]$ openssl s_client -connect openvpn.example.com:1194
CONNECTED(00000003)
140413456672632:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:184:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 205 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

I can only presume that although OpenVPN uses SSL, it does so in a different way from a standard SSL/TLS connection.  So I don't think this is the way to go.

I'd hoped to find an `openvpn` client invocation that would dump the certficates, but thus far have not.  I'm sorry not to have more for you, but I thought it worth writing an answer that might prevent you from wasting time.

Comment: See my comment on the original post; Openvpn uses DTLS for TLS over UDP. I was able to connect to (but not dump from) an openvpn server I was running.

Comment: Having just tried it, I can't agree: it merely prints "`CONNECTED(00000003)`" (which is meaningless in a UDP context).  `tcpdump` confirms that this message appears as soon as the first UDP packet is *sent* to the server - and no reply is received.  I reiterate my view that `openssl s_client` can't help you.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem and it can be resolved by using openvpn with particular arguments. The important ones are `--tls-verify` and `--tls-export-cert`. `--tls-verify` needs to be followed by filename of a script you want to execute. The environment variable `peer_cert` will contain a location of the dumped certificate chain. The `--tls-export-cert` needs to be followed by a directory name where the certificate will be dumped. The certificate is auto-deleted once the tls-verify script finishes.

The only problem I found was that it requires you to already have the CA certificate. If you don't have it, the script won't execute and I haven't found a way to work around it.

Example in use:

```
openvpn --remote remote.host.to.check 1194 --dev tun --proto udp --ca tmp/openvpnca.cert --client --auth-user-pass tmp/noauth.txt --remote-cert-tls server --tls-verify tmp/tls-verify.sh --script-security 2 --tls-export-cert tmp/tlsverifies
```

`tmp/noauth.txt` is a dummy file with two lines containing a fake username/password.
`tmp/tlsverifies` is a directory where the chain file will be dumped.
`tmp/tls-verify.sh` is a shell script that processes the `peer_cert` environment variable

Comment: So what should go in `tls-verify.sh`?

Comment: Also, all of your `tmp` directory references should be prefixed with `/`, and you need to `chmod 600 /tmp/noauth.txt`

Comment: This answer is going in the right direction but is incomplete.

Comment: @Reinderien `tls-verify.sh` should accept an environment variable `peer_cert` (which will contain the peer certificate) and process it. At least that's what I think based on the my original answer. I'm moving from openvpn to wireguard so I'm not spending time on this anymore.